# Laravel `orWhereIn` is making `whereNotIn` not take effect

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have query that `orWhereIn` is making `whereNotIn`  not take effect and I dont get the desired result! the column on those two are different.

When I change the order of these query pieces sometimes it only repeats the last row sometimes the last 3 , and sometimes the result is way out of expectation

```php
$userposts = userPost::with([
    //RELATIONS--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    'getUser.userbaseinfo',
    'getUser.usercertinfo',
    'getUser.getJobexp',
    'getLike'                           => function ($q) {
        $q->where('liked', 1);
        $q->orderByRaw("FIELD(user_id ," . auth()->user()->id . ") DESC");
    },
    'getLike.getUser.Userbaseinfo',
    'getLike.usercertinfo.getmajor',
    'getLike.usercertinfo.getuniversity',
    'getLike.userjobexp.getCompany',
    'getLike.getcandidate',
    'getLike.userbaseinfo',
    'gettags',
    'getCandidate.getBaseinfo',
    'getCandidate.getCertificate.getmajor',
    'getCandidate.getCertificate.getuniversity',
    'getCandidate.candidjobexp.getCompany',
    'getComments'                       => function ($q) {
        $q->orderByRaw("FIELD(user_id ," . auth()->user()->id . ") DESC");
    },
    'getComments.userbaseinfo',
    'getComments.getcandidate',
    'getComments.usercertinfo.getmajor',
    'getComments.usercertinfo.getuniversity',
    'getComments.userjobexp.getCompany',
    'getfriendreq'                      => function ($q) {
        $q->where('requester_id', auth()->user()->id);
    },
    'getfollow'                         => function ($q) {
        $q->where('req_id', auth()->user()->id);
    },
    'getComments.getLike'               => function ($q) {
        $q->orderByRaw("FIELD(user_id ," . auth()->user()->id . ") DESC");
        $q->where('liked', 1);
    },
    'getComments.getLike.getcandidate',
    'getComments.getLike.getuser',
    'getComments.getLike.Userbaseinfo',
    'getComments.getLike.usercertinfo',
    'getComments.getLike.Userjobexp'    => function ($q) {
        $q->limit(1);
    },
    'getsharedpost.getUser.userbaseinfo',
    'getsharedpost.getUser.usercertinfo',
    'getsharedpost.getUser.getJobexp',
    'getsharedpost.getCandidate',
    'getComments.childcomments'         => function ($q) {
        $q->orderByRaw("FIELD(user_id ," . auth()->user()->id . ") DESC");
    },
    'getComments.childcomments.userjobexp',
    'getComments.childcomments.getcandidate',
    'getComments.childcomments.usercertinfo',
    'getComments.childcomments.userbaseinfo',
    'getComments.childcomments.getLike' => function ($q) {
        $q->orderByRaw("FIELD(user_id ," . auth()->user()->id . ") DESC");
        $q->where('liked', 1);
    },
    'getComments.childcomments.getLike.getuser',
    'getComments.childcomments.getLike.userjobexp',
    'getComments.childcomments.getLike.getcandidate',
    'getComments.childcomments.getLike.usercertinfo',
    'getComments.childcomments.getLike.userbaseinfo'])
    //END OF RELATION----------------------------------------------------------------

    //If I change these query piece order the result might be changed
    ->whereHas('gettags', function ($q) use ($TagsToLook) {
        $q->whereIn('tag_id', $TagsToLook);
    });

$userposts = $userposts->orWhereIn('user_id', $Sourceloader)->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id);

if (count($lastpostid) > 0) {
    $userposts = $userposts->whereNotIn('post_id', $lastpostid);
}

$result = $userposts->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit(3)->get();
```

Desired  result:showing posts with the relations that has not been shown `Where` its not the loggedIn user `orWhere` user_id is equal to $sourceloader.

Actual result: If the posts those are in `whereNotIn` ($lastpostid) are from users that their id is in $sourceloader then `whereNotIn` wont take effect and it will keep showing the previous posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what you want is to fetch results where either `tag_id` is in a given set or `user_id` is in a given set as long as, in either case, `post_id` isn't in a given set. In that case you need to group the `tag_id` and `user_id` conditions.

```php
->where(function($query) use ($TagsToLook) {
  return $query
    ->whereHas('gettags', function ($q) use ($TagsToLook) {
      $q->whereIn('tag_id', $TagsToLook);
    })
    ->orWhereIn('user_id', $Sourceloader);
});
```

This is equivalent to putting them in parentheses in raw SQL. You can read about this [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations) under "Chaining orWhere Clauses After Relationships".

Comment: just to clarify , if I have couple of certain set and another one which is not certain , I have to group the certain ones ?

Comment: When I said "a certain set" I just meant a set that you defined. You need to group the conditions that go together logically e.g. "(this one or that one) and this one".

Comment: Oh okay, thought u mean because  dont have `if` statement we group them together. Grouping conditions with same logic make sense. Thanks again